# Overriding val defined in interface by using var with the same name defined in superclass

Tags: interface, kotlin, subclass, superclass

There is a ***Base*** class (**var** needs to stay protected):

```
open class Base(protected var id: Int) {}
```

There is an interface which needs to use **val**:

```
interface ProviderI {
    val id: Int
}
```

There is also a class which inherits from ***Base*** and implements the ***ProviderI*** interface. Within which I'm trying to implement the interface's **val** using the superclass **var** (which has the same name).
As a not working example, I'm trying to do something like that (example does not work):

```
class Instance(id: Int): Base(id), ProviderI {
    override val id
        get() { return super.id }
}
```

The idea is simple but I've tried everything and every time different error is reported.

Comment: Can your Base class be abstract?

Comment: Also, it's not really clear WHY you are trying to do this. It seems overly complicated.

Comment: @dillius, the class cannot be abstract, it's not the class I can modify. It's also not complicated at all, I have one class which is already implemented in comapany's framework, let's assume it's Base. I have also client's interface, let's assume it's ProviderI. So the problem is real, I just wonder how to solve it.

Comment: @dillius out of the curiosity (it's not the case I can use here, but still curious), if the Base was abstract. What would it change?

Comment: Nothing significant. It just gives you other options for how to specify the ID property in the Base class itself if you could edit it.

Comment: Another idea: Could you use a proxy/adapter to contain the Base as a component in your Instance, rather than having the instance as a subclass of it? Or do you genuinely need one class to extend both?

Answer (score 4):

To override a member that is present in several supertypes, Kotlin requires it to be `open` in **all supertypes**, and this restriction looks quite natural, because otherwise `final` members could be easily overridden in this way.

The solution is to make `id` open in `Base` as well and to override it as a `var` property:

```
open class Base(protected open var id: Int)

interface ProviderI {
    val id: Int
}

class Instance(id: Int): Base(id), ProviderI {
    override var id: Int
        get() = super.id
        set(value) { super.id = value }
}
```

Comment: As I wrote in response to @dillius answer, I cannot modify the Base class. I'm just looking for the way to implement the interface.

Comment: If you can not modify the base class, there really is no reasonable way to use the same property name again. Can you change the property name on the interface?

Comment: @dillius, I also cannot modify the interface, Only the class in the middle is mine. Base class is my company's framework class, widely use in different places. Interface is our client's code, it also cannot be modified as it's now ours.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin does not allow `val` properties to override `var` properties.

Closest thing that will work:

```
open class Base(protected open var id: Int) {}

interface ProviderI {
    val id: Int
}

class Instance(id: Int): Base(id), ProviderI {
    override var id: Int = 0
        get() { return super.id }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify the Base class. The main point is to find the way to implement the interface without modifying the Base class. Although your solution is close to the one expected by me.